# Sklearn f1_score with Unexpected Results

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to evaluate a machine learning system by calculating the f1_score with Scikit-learn on my predictions. However, the results are not as expected. Calling the confusion_matrix shows

```
[[ 3 11]
 [ 5 31]]
```

If I calculate the f1 score by hand as 2*(precision * recall) / (precision + recall), I get 2*(3/8 * 31/42)/(3/8 + 31/42) = 0.497. But calling f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average="binary") yields 0.7949. Does anybody have an explanation?

Even if I call f1_score with constant predictions of 1 when the true labels are mixed, I'm getting high scores instead of the 0 with a warning I'm expecting. I suspect the f1_score is not what I'm expecting for avg="binary", but I can't wrap my head around it.

My scikit-learn version is 0.21.3.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake calculating precision and recall values manually.

Precision = TruePositives / (TruePositives + FalsePositives)

Recall = TruePositives / (TruePositives + FalseNegatives)

Please revise your calculation! You will get 0.7949 value when you correct!

Comment: This is so emberassing. Thank you for your reply. I somehow confused precision with specificity/true negative ratio. The f1 score is probably misleading in my case of fairly unbalanced classes, if simply classifying everything as 1 returns fairly good looking scores of ~0.8.